# Can't see some folders on external hard drive

Tags: directory

(Ubuntu 16.04)
Some folders on my external drive (a Western Digital Passport) do not show up in nautilus. 
If I type the folder name in the search box, it shows up and I can navigate in it and access the files. 
In a terminal, I can navigate to the folder normally and carry out the usual commands (ls etc). 
Decidedly odd! 
Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: Can you give some examples of foldernames ?

Comment: Some of the folder names that don't show up:

Comment: Sorry, pressed return and then couldn't edit the answer. I've gone through the list of folders displayed in the terminal and compared them with the nautilus display. It turns out that there are only two, Videos and TV progs.

Comment: When I plugged the drive into my wife's Windows computer, all the folders showed up.  I've looked at all the permissions, but can't see any difference.

Comment: When I plugged it back into my computer (Ubuntu), after plugging into my wife's Windows machine, all the folders now show up. So it works, but I really would like to understand.